# Socket from linux C to Windows C# issues

Tags: c#, c, linux, sockets

Here is what I'm doing.  Basically I have some code in linux C processing a bunch of data that I then need to send to a C# app that can graph the data in "real time" ish.  So what I was doing was saving the data to a file and having the C# app just watch for file changes and then update the graph then.  But that was really not working that great.  The file was reading that it was being changing more often than it just wasn't fun.  So after taking some advice from some helpful folks on here I decided to learn about sending the data using sockets.

So here is what I'm doing now. Process data in C send to C# using socket stuff.  Totally works ish.  But here is the problem.  I need to use usleep(10000) after sending the info, or use getchar() and send each value slowly.  Otherwise I get an error trying to convert the value sent to a double.

The error reads "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.  at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt).

```
sprintf(line, "%.4f", value[i][j]);
write(sock, line, 128);
usleep(10000);
```

C# code taken from the example found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463947/Working-with-Sockets-in-Csharp

Problem is here:

```
content = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
chart4.Series["Graph"].Points.Add(Convert.ToDouble(content.ToString()));
```

So why does it work when I pause after sending data but not if I send it without pausing?  Am I sending it too fast?

Also if I have 4 different charts that need to receive a constant flow of data should I have 4 different sockets like each one a different port number so I know which one is receiving data?  Sorry for the noob questions.  I'm trying to learn this stuff on my own.  I'm still in school and haven't learned anything even remotely similar yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP sockets are streams. They have no concept of messages. When you send too quickly, several calls to send are received in one call, which results in an attempt to parse parts of several numbers.

I would recommend that you choose one of these options:

1. Add a delimiter between each sample.
2. Use a protocol which is message based, not stream based.
3. Write fixed-size messages. For example, just send the raw 8 bytes of the `double` and use a `BinaryReader` to read them.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Is one of these methods better than another?  It seems to me that adding a delimiter is easiest, but maybe not the best way.

Comment: There are a number of schools of thought on that. I personally would go with #3, but keep in mind that the format of a native double is not specified for C, so the C program may not be portable to other platforms if you just write out the bytes directly.

Comment: Oh also does it make sense that each chart will have its own socket port number?  I don't know how else to tell which chart should be receiving what info.

Comment: Is all your data sent at the same frequency? If so, use 8 bytes for each and send them each sequentially over the same socket. (That would work with the delimited approach also)

Comment: Yes it is.  So I can send the 4 values to the same socket just fine and my charts update perfectly.  So I think this kind of works now.  I'm going to read up on what you recommended and see if I can get anywhere.  I'm actually really surprised that I even got this far.  Thanks for the suggestions.